# Valid SSL certificate for domain/subdomain pointed at a private IP address

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, ssl, internal-dns, private-ip

This is related to a question I saw [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/608507/dns-a-record-pointing-to-private-ip-address) where the OP asks whether you can point an A record to a private IP address. So it seems like you can but I have a further question...

If I create the subdomain `private` on `mydomain.com` and point this to the private ip address `10.10.1.234`, can I then use my wildcard SSL certificate for `*.mydomain.com` so that `https://private.mydomain.com` has a proper/valid certificate for internal clients?

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference between private ([RFC1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918)) and public IP addresses except that the former are not routable on the Internet and the latter are.

Your DNS zones can point to both these private and public IP addresses as to the DNS — and to routers and other devices — there is no difference between private and public IP addresses. Your SSL/TLS certificates aren't concerned with IP addresses at all and only care about DNS names. Your certificate is valid if it is signed and you use it on the correct website.

Thus to answer your question, your wildcard certificate will work and be valid as it is a wild card certificate for your domain. The IP address pointed to by the A record is of no significance.